# How to remove a specific line in dart as per given line number starting from 0

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose we have a file containing the following data

```
line number 0
line number 1
line number 2
line number 3
line number 4
```

I want to remove the index 2nd line starting from 0 so that the output file becomes

```
line number 0
line number 1
line number 3
line number 4
```

Comment: from a string variable or something else ?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: @OMiShah I want to work directly with the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
final index = 5; // remove the 6th line

File f = new File('test.txt');
f.readAsLines().then((List<String> lines) {
  lines.removeAt(index);
  final newTextData = lines.join('\n');
  f.writeAsString(newTextData); // update the file with the new data
});
```

Answer (score 5):

While OMi's answer is correct, there's no need to use `then()` here if you don't need this to be performed asynchronously. You can also do the following within an asynchronous function to ensure the operation is completed when you expect:

```dart
Future<void> myAsyncFunction() async {
  final index = 5;
  final File f = File('test.txt');
  final List<String> lines = await f.readAsLines();
  lines.removeAt(index);
  await f.writeAsString(lines.join('\n'));
}
```

Also, it's worth noting that there's synchronous versions for most IO methods (e.g., `f.readAsLinesSync()`) which perform the same operation in a blocking manner, but you should prefer awaiting the asynchronous versions to avoid blocking the event queue from handling other asynchronous events while you're waiting for the operation to complete.